# How to install QuickTime 7 without overwriting the currently installed version

Tags: macbook-pro, install, quicktime

I purchased a Intel MacBook Pro from a colleague with installed OS 10.8.5. I do not own the OS disks therefore do not have the disks to re-install QuickTime. QT 10.2 is on this "new" 2008 MacBookPro. The question relates to the need to install QT 7 which has the dialog box to register the key code to unlock the Pro features (QT 10.2 lacks the ability to enter the Pro key hence the need to install QT 7 then upgrade). How might I install QT7 and still retain the QT 10.2 version on the MacBook Pro, as I don't have the option of reinstalling 10.2 if written over. (I don't want to risk "losing" QT 10.2 on OS 10.8.5 because it will block the ability to use Final Cut Pro 7 or X). Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The QuickTime Player 7 and QuickTime 10 apps coexist on all my Macs without causing any problems.

If you're worried about overwriting QuickTime Player 10, right-click on the app, and choose Compress "QuickTime Player.app" and zip it up. If the QuickTime Player 7 installation wipes out v.10, (and I don't think it will,) then you can simply uncompress it.

You can also retrieve it from a Time Machine backup. You *do* use Time Machine, don't you?

Comment: Thank you. I do use Time Machine to recover the app if necessary.